# How to create an object requires multiple bounded contexts?

Tags: design, domain-driven-design, microservices

I will describe my problem with a very typical example, an e-commerce application.

Says we have to manage `Products`, and we have 2 bounded contexts `Sales`, and `Warehouse` that store the product information.

The `Sales` bounded context cares about price, product name, description.

The `Warehouse` bounded context cares about sizes, position, quantity, quality.

When we *create* a new product, we have to input all of the above information. Following the CQRS pattern, we have to send 2 commands `Create Product` to `Sales` and `Warehouse` bounded context, which could be 2 microservices.

The problem is, if the `Product` is created in `Sales`, but not valid to be created in `Warehouse`, or the command to `Warehouse` is not sent, then the `Product` in `Sales` does not make sense. The same goes with the reverse.

So how do you create an object, in this case, a product, that appears in multiple bounded contexts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Product` objects in two different bounded contexts should be usually seen as two different objects which share the same name "just by coincidence". Of course, this is not completely coincidentally, since both objects will be a representation of the same physical item, but those two `Product` classes can (and will) represent very different aspects of a real-world "product". This may go as far as storing  products in the warehouse by their quantity (one `Product` object represents multiple real-world items, counted by quantity), and storing products in `Sales` in a 1:1 manner to their real-world pendant.

So in each bounded context, there is a creation process for its own `Product` objects, implemented in some kind of `Product` factory. These processes should be completely independent from the other bounded context.

Now let's assume, for example, there is a use case "Advertise Product" from `Sales`, which checks if the product is available in the warehouse, and only creates the sales-related `Product` object when there is still a corresponding product in the warehouse. Then in the context of *this use case*, the related `Product` factory from `Sales` has to query `Warehouse` whether there are products of the give type in stock (this query may utilize a tempory warehouse `Product` object, which should be created by the `Sales` independent creation process). If the query to `Warehouse` fails, "Advertise Product" won't deliver any saled `Products`.

Same could work the other way round: say there is a use case "reorder products" from `Warehouse`, and for determining the reorder quantity, `Warehouse` needs to ask `Sales` how many advance bookings for a certain product are already there. Then the creation process of "reorder products" will issue a query for the related products from `Sales`. In case there will be nothing returned, "reorder products" won't create any warehouse `Products` for reordering, or maybe just fewer ones.

So in short:

- see `Warehouse.Product` and `Sales.Product` as different products, which can be created independently - hence the create commands should stay independent
- there may be certain use cases which forbid independend creation of a product object on one context if it is not available in the other - if so,  model and implement those use cases, for example, as a service, but don't try to stuff a whole use case implementation into a single creation command.

Comment: Base on your answer, I can see the `Warehouse.Product` and `Sales.Product` are different. The `Product` add to `Sales` goes into a catalog. The `Product` add to `Warehouse` is the physical product, if I get it right. When the user queries for the `Sales.Product` to buy, does the `Sales` have to check the `Product` in the `Warehouse`? If this happens, every query the `Sales` needs to update the information of `Product` in `Warehouse`. Is this true? Is there any better practice?

Comment: "The Product add to Warehouse is the physical product,"- no, both product objects are just a model, implemented in the bits and bytes of your computers. The physical product is what UPS delivers to your home.

Comment: "When the user queries for the Sales.Product to buy, does the Sales have to check the Product in the Warehouse?" - maybe, that depends totally on how **you** design **your** system and **your** use cases, and how you distribute the information between different parts of the system. Amazon, for examples, can offer you products and prices on their web site even if those products are out of stock (and they show you that information before you buy anything). So in case there is a "Sales" and a "Warehouse" microservice behind that (which I don't know), ...

Comment: .. I guess "Sales" would have to query "Warehouse" for *this kind of use case*, that's quite normal. But that does not imply that *every* query for a product in "Sales" would require also a query to "Warehouse", I have no idea why you come to this conclusion.